# DataBind does not generate controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have CheckBox lists that I need to add attributes to but I have noticed that when I iterate the controls, there are none...

```
    var listType = SettingsManager.Get("CRMCaseTypes");
    var listStatus = SettingsManager.Get("CRMStatusReasons");

    var listTypeItems = ParseSettingList(listType);
    var listStatusItems = ParseSettingList(listStatus);

    cblCRMType.DataSource = listTypeItems;
    cblCRMType.DataBind();
    cblCRMStatus.DataSource = listStatusItems;
    cblCRMStatus.DataBind();

    int index = 0;
    foreach (Control c in cblCRMStatus.Controls)
    {
        CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
        if (cb != null)
        {
            cb.Attributes.Add("id", listStatusItems[index].Value);

            if (cb.Attributes["id"] == "5")
            {
                cb.Checked = true;
                cb.Enabled = false;
            }
        }

        index++;
    }

    index = 0;
    foreach (Control c in cblCRMType.Controls)
    {
        CheckBox cb = c as CheckBox;
        if (cb != null)
        {
            cb.Attributes.Add("id", listTypeItems[index].Value);
        }

        index++;
    }

}
```

Is there a way to force the checkbox generation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `DataBind()` on a `CheckBoxList`, it populates its `Items` collection, not its `Controls` collection.

```
foreach (ListItem item in cblCRMStatus.Items)
{
    if (item.Value == "5")
    {
        item.Selected = true;
        item.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

The `item.Attributes` property lets you add additional attributes to the check box. However, you cannot set the `id` attribute; ASP.NET automatically sets it to an incrementing integer.

Comment: Yes, I have noticed that, so how can I get the checkboxes to give them attributes?

Comment: I stil need to give them a value somehow, Im not just setting enabled/disabled.

Comment: The `ListItem.Selected` property corresponds to the checked/unchecked state.

Comment: And the `ListItem.Value` property contains the value of the property on the data item identified by the [`DataValueField`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.aspx) property.